# Multiple Likes in SQL

Tags: sql

Please review the following code and help me in fixing the error.

When i'm trying to execute it i'm getting only the records which were starting with the ENTBI-Q.But the two conditions which were written below(task%,INC%) were not getting executed.

I want the records which starts with task,incident and entbi-q.

Please note that the task and incident are the field values of one column and the entbi-q is the field values of the another coloumn.

```
SELECT
   S1."NAME" AS "NAME",
   S1."SYS_ID" AS "SYSID",
   T2."ASSIGNMENT_GROUP" AS "ASSIGNMENTGROUP",
   T2."NUMBER_" AS "NUMBER",
   T2."CLOSED_AT" AS "CLOSEDAT",
   T2."OPENED_AT" AS "OPENEDAT"

FROM
   "IOD"."SYS_USER_GROUP" S1,
   "IOD"."TASK" T2
WHERE
   (S1."SYS_ID"=T2."ASSIGNMENT_GROUP")
   AND  S1."NAME" LIKE 'ENTBI-Q%'
   AND T2."NUMBER" LIKE 'TASK%'
   AND T2."NUMBER" LIKE 'INC%'
```

Comment: `t2.number` can't start with both `TASK` **and** `INC`. Can you share some sample data and the result you'd like to get for that? Maybe it would clarify the question for us.

Answer (score 5):

```
AND T2."NUMBER" LIKE 'TASK%'
AND T2."NUMBER" LIKE 'INC%'
```

This can never be true. If a string starts with `TASK` it cannot start with `INC`. You probably wanted to `OR` the two conditions:

```
AND (T2."NUMBER" LIKE 'TASK%'
OR T2."NUMBER" LIKE 'INC%')
```